# HTML AGILITY PACK Parsing Div Blocks

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

I need to parse items from an internet-shop—I need their name and price. Each *item-block* is located in a different `div` within a `div-catalog` of these items.
So I tried this, and it kinda works, but I would prefer to parse both name and price in 1 loop. How might I do so? Thanks!

```
        var url = "http://bestaqua.com.ua/catalog/filtry-obratnogo-osmosa";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument HtmlDoc = web.Load(url);
        var RootNode = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode;
        foreach (HtmlNode node in 
HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='catalog_blocks']"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode item_name in 
node.SelectNodes("//div[@class='catalog_blocks-item-name']"))
            {
                    string name = item_name.InnerText;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("NAME :" + name + "\n" );
            }
            foreach (HtmlNode item_price in 
node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='price-new']"))
            {
                string price = item_price.InnerText;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("PRICE: " + price + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SelectNodes` is using an [XPATH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx)-expression, you could just use a [union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) in your class filter using "|", which will result in a single collection to loop over.
Note that you would then still need to check which element you've actually selected within the for-loop.